# Probability of a big coastal storm accruing twice over twenty years

Tags: probability

I know how to determine the probability of a $100$ yr storm is $1\%$ per year, and I know how to calculate the probability of at least one storm taking place over $20$ years $(1-.99^{20})$ but I am not sure how to calculate the probability of two storms happening over the $20$ yr period (assuming the storms are independent events).  Can anyone help here?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The probability that there are at least two storms is the $1$ minus the probability of not storms, minus the probability of exactly $1$ storm.  For the latter probability there are $20$ choices for what year the storm occurs, so the probability is $$20\cdot.01\cdot.99^{19}$$